# Concatenate Label Values Fails to Calculate Aggregate

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2.18, concatenation

I'm trying to do what seems like a very simple operation (It's SUPER easy in ArcMap...). I'm kind of a novice with QGIS, so it's probably something really simple that I'm doing incorrectly. The release is 2.18.12. Basically, I want to create concatenated labels with values from three separate fields, separated in the text by a comma and a space. The fields I'm trying to concatenate are numeric and have no null values (unless zero is considered null). Here is my expression:

[image]

Here is the error summary:

[image]

This is ridiculously easy in ArcMap using a JavaScript expression. Heeeeelp!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing two functions. You could use either:

```
TOWNSHIP || ',' || RANGE || ',' || ISP_SECTIO
```

or

```
concat( TOWNSHIP, ',', RANGE, ',', ISP_SECTIO )
```

The concat version is a bit safer, since it will automatically treat NULL values like an empty string.

- Note use of "concat", not "concatenate" (which is a different function)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, the coalesce function only returns one value per feature. The first format that you suggested did the trick, though.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant concat